# When is the Chiesa di San Maurizio al Monastero Maggiore open?

Tags: italy, milan

I don't read Italian, so I can't understand the webpage for the Chiesa di San Maurizio al Monastero Maggiore. I found two other websites (yelp and stay.com) that give conflicting opening hours.

What are the opening hours?

Comment: are you looking for mass or just visiting opening hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This is the official tourism site](http://www.turismo.milano.it/wps/portal/!ut/p/c0/04_SB8K8xLLM9MSSzPy8xBz9CP0os3hzS0O_QGcLEwMLFzcjA08LAz8TH2cnAwMDI_3g1Dz9gmxHRQCFp8TT/?WCM_GLOBAL_CONTEXT=/en/situr/home/artecultura/architettura/loc542) and you can actually find the timetable for Chiesa di San Maurizio al Monastero Maggiore:

> Timetable:    Tue-Sat: 09:30am-5:30pm
>   Ticket:     Free entrance. Reservations are required for groups: phone to 0039.02.20404175.